# Is there any term for tailoring data to the suitability of different models?

Tags: machine-learning, data-transformation, dataset

Is there any literature or fields I could start with, if I was asked grade each of a bunch of datasets, or assess their suitability for different model types, and inference goals?

Comment: There are AutoML libraries doing automated selection of models but we would still need to specify input data structure and type of modelling.

Comment: Any idea about the other way around?

Comment: It is still part of AutoML topics. One could check here https://www.automl.org if there are any papers related to this.